# There are answers to your questions awaiting your review/approval

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

While the new bar is out and it seems very controversial ie. 10+ questions per hour about it I am gonna drop in a new idea.

Over the last year I have stumbled around a good amount of new users who have asked multiple questions and have not accepted any answers as they may not be aware of such a feature on Stack Overflow.

I am proposing a new drop drown with the links to user's questions which have answers (*or upvoted answers*) to make it easier for those new ones to the site to realize that such a feature exists which makes it unique and different from any forum (*or most of them at least*).

Add a new drop down icon next to the inbox and reputation **ONLY** for new users who have not accepted any answers yet.

something like this but much prettier

[image]

and within the context add text like

one of your questions has been asnwered / *or has upvoted answers*. Please review it and consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Make the above a hyper link and when a new user clicks it he's redirected to the question.

as simple as that ->

- [you like](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QT7bhJTkAs) +1
- you don't think this is cool 0
- terrible idea -1

Comment: I would put that drop down for questions without accepted answer for everyone, not just new comers.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I got into a habit of rather checking users profiles before attempting to answer their questions - specifically, I am talking about poor questions.

Answer (score 8):

1. Real estate on the New Black™ is extremely limited, and (in my opinion) this feature doesn't justify the cost of that many pixels.
2. The symbol is ambiguous.  What does it mean?  Sure, you're going to put a tooltip on it, but...
3. We already have several reminders directed at new users about accepting answers.
4. If you really need another reminder, it should probably go into the inbox as its own message.  Which would be no less obnoxious.
5. Accepting answers is an entirely optional activity anyway.

Comment: I can't reproduce the new users experience without actually creating a new account every week or so. I still do see new people asking multiple questions and do not bother accepting upvoted answers - dont bother or don't know? from own experience they just didnt know! So I dont know what the current reminders are so maybe you can  elaborate? By saying *prettier* I mean't override the check mark with something *prettier*. (5)agree, so are SO-Careers but I got an email asking to invite new people to it and encourage them to use it... there is a thin line between what SO does to its own advantage.